# MS Access: How to Programmatically Add a Subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to programmatically add a subform to a form using Access VBA?  I have a temporary table that is generated dynamically when requested by the user.  If possible, I would like to create a form based on the temporary table and add it as a subform to a pre-existing form.

Comment: Why? Why not use an existing subform and change the recordsource and the fields the controls are bound to at runtime? Design changes in a production app is a really amateur way to do things, in my opinion.

Comment: You do not need to change design to set a source object, it can be done at run time and a subform control is just as happy to display a table or query as a form.

Comment: And, in this case, there can be anywhere from 3 to 50+ fields - Unnecessarily cluttering the form with 50+ static fields when the user only asks for 3 makes for a poor user interface.

Comment: The question says "ADD" at runtime, not CHANGE, so I read it as a request for design changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best bet is to create the subform control and set the source object to either a table or a query.

```
Me.NameOfSubformControl.SourceObject = "Query.Query1"
Me.NameOfSubformControl.SourceObject = "Table.Temp"
```

It is also possible to update the sql of a saved query to reference the new temp table.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Why? You are setting the source to a table or query not a form so controls are not relevant. I am afraid what you say is not true.

Comment: That seems to work very well. No need to fool with any controls in this case.

Comment: I misread. You are suggesting setting the subform's SourceObject (which is what you said, of course, but I didn't read carefuilly). I'm deleting the comment.